# Access for external employees suddenly no longer possible

Tags: access, user-accounts, access-denied, microsoft-access, external-users

external is added to list and does not appear in this list.

the external had already accessed and was able to edit the documents, etc., this access was suddenly no longer possible for no apparent reason.

does anyone have a solution as the access can be granted again ?

Unfortunately the simple addition and also the new creation of a sharepoint group did not work.

Thanks in advance :)